# Why the for loop is not working?

Tags: javascript, string

I am working on a problem ask me to:

Move the first letter of each word to the end of it, then add 'ay' to the end of the word.

```
pigIt('Pig latin is cool'); //igPay atinlay siay oolcay
```

Here is code i have for now and it only returns the first word although it used a for loop. This might be a stupid mistake but I am just kinda stuck here and would really appreciate your help checking the code out.(it might just be I've been looking at it for too long and a fresh pair of eyes would definitely catch the bug)

```
function pigIt(str) {

str = str.split(" ")
 for(var i = 0;i<str.length;i++)
 return str[i].slice(1)+str[i][0]+"ay"
}

console.log(pigIt('Pig latin is cool'))
```

And also i think my solution can be simplified using a nested map function but my attempt wasnt successful; could any of you come up with a better solution to the problem presented?

Thanks guys.

UPDATE:

so Here is a working map code i was looking for, much better than my original solution:

```
 function pigIt(str){
 return str.split(' ').map(function(el){
  return el.slice(1) + el.slice(0,1) + 'ay';
  }).join(' ');
 }
```

just if someone else stumbled upon this question and want to use a simplified code for the problem.

Comment: As soon as you `return` once, that's it - your function stops. You need to remember each word somehow, then return the whole thing at the end.

Comment: your loop will stop on the first iteration! The return is called only once, not for each `i`

Comment: You shouldn't be calling `return` in the loop. It is making the loop exit early.

Comment: Learn more about functions: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Functions

Comment: A one liner `str.replace(/(\w)(\w+)/g, '$2$1ay')`

Comment: @elclanrs thanks though Im still trying to get the hang of regex but nice!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here you go:

```
var str = 'pig latin is cool',
    strArr = [];

str.split(' ').forEach(function (piece, index, arr) {
    piece = piece.slice(1) + piece[0] + 'ay';
    strArr.push(piece);
});

alert(strArr.join(' '));
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/6fdx2mcs/

Comment: I appreciate the use of for each but the code seems to have bugs. it returns undefined.

Comment: @BRAYBRAY, you'd appreciate `map` even more!

Answer (score 6):

Your are using `return` in your `for` loop, so it executes the first iteration, and... returns.

You need to push the contents onto an array, and then join back the array into a string.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. in my case I tried appending the result to an array but why it fails to use push on the object (str[i].slice(1)+str[i][0]+"ay")?

Answer (score 2):

I would like to share a version using **Regular Expressions** to offer a side view of this issue.

A regular expression like:  `/(\w)(\w+)/g`

- **`\w`** = will match the first letter of any word character from `[a-zA-Z0-9_]` if it is necessary to exclude the `_` and numbers better can be `[a-zA-Z]`
- **`(\w+)`** = will match the rest of the word of any word character from `[a-zA-Z0-9_]` if it is necessary to exclude the `_` and numbers better can be `[a-zA-Z]`

**Example:**

```
"Pig latin is cool".replace(/(\w)(\w+)/g,"$2$1ay") //returns igPay atinlay siay oolcay
```

Will produce the desired result as well.

- **`$1`** represents the first group `(\w)`
- **`$2`** represents the second group `(\w+)`
- `ay` is the expression that is needs to be added to every word.

Also a good candidate for a prototype method:

```
String.prototype.igPay = function () {
    return this.replace(/(\w)(\w+)/g,"$2$1ay");
}
"Pig latin is cool".igPay();
```

Demo : http://jsfiddle.net/cytms60c/